# Open a new line below current line in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there any easy way to open a new line below current line in Xcode text editor? Currently I have to press cmd+right and enter for this purpose. Eclipse (Shift+Enter) and vim (o) can do that with simple key combination.

Answer (score 11):

You can take a look at this tutorial about how to add custom keyboard shortcut in Xcode  ---[Xcode duplicate line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-4-duplicate-line), then just add a new key-value `Insert New Line Below Current Line` `moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:` in IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist file, at last config your Key Bindings (like Shift+Enter) in Xcode.

Comment: Its a shame apple didn't think about defining custom key shortcuts. anyway thanks a lot. it helps me

Answer (score 3):

I don't think XCode supports that shortcut.

Check the `Key Bindings` preferences.  Search for "line" under the Text tab.

There are lots of "Insert Newline" commands for which you can set key combos.  There's Ctrl+o, Cmd+Enter, Opt+Enter, etc.  But I don't think it's possible to do natively.

Comment: `Ctrl-o` worked for me without going into preferences. (XCode 4.5.2)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

**1.** open this file

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist
```

**2.** option click (context menu) and select **Add Row**

**3.** Give any name (e.g My Custom) choose **Dictionary as it's type

**4.** click + icon on this new dictionary.
a new field will appear, enter your preferred name (e.g insert new line below).

**5.** enter moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline: as it's value

**6.** save the file.

**7.** quit and relaunch Xcode

**8.** open preferences, go to key bindings and search for your name *insert new line below*

assign a shortcut.

enjoy!

[image]

[image]

**NOTES**
if you have permissions problem in saving the file. just copy the file to your desktop, edit it, and then move the file to the location
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

Answer (score 1):

I found that `moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:` did not work for me. Instead, this worked `moveToEndOfLine:, insertLineBreak:`. I am using Xcode 13.4.1